# google android In-app purchase testing issues

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

My app is published in alpha, and allows for purchasing a yearly subscription with a 7-days trial period.

I just tested the purchase process with a test account (declared as such in dev console).

The purchase went ok, and the user received a mail confirming his purchase. This mail is full of mistakes:

1) the price is without tax, which is confusing

2) It says the trial-period will expire tomorrow, instead of in 7 days (we are on Feb 27):

> You have signed up for a free trial subscription from xxx on Google
>   Play. Your trial will end on Feb 28, 2015. You will be automatically
>   subscribed for €15.83/day at the end of your trial unless you cancel.

3) Funnily enough, it says that after the trial period, he will be charged DAILY, instead of yearly:

> By subscribing you authorize us to charge you the subscription cost
>   (currently €15.83/day) automatically, charged daily to the payment
>   method provided. You can cancel at any time

Moreover, I couldn't find a way to cancel the subscription. I went to the wallet account of the user, no transaction there. Same thing in the merchant wallet account from my side. How am I supposed to cancel the transaction and try again eventually?

The only good point is that my app and google api (V3) recognizes that the user has purchased the subscription.

Maybe it's just because I declared the user as a test-user in google-dev console?

Thanks in advance for any input or advice.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it says 'day' instead of year is answered here:

[Android In App BIlling v3 - Wrong Subscription Trial Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444481/android-in-app-billing-v3-wrong-subscription-trial-period)

> This is a normal response. I guess you're testing with an account
>   added as a tester to Google Play account. Test subscriptions are valid
>   for 1 day and get cancelled after 1 day.
>
> Quoting the official docs
>   http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html
>
> Note: Test subscription purchases recur daily, regardless of the
>   product's subscription period.