# Android In App BIlling v3 - Wrong Subscription Trial Period

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using the  Android In App BIlling v3  library, and when I call

```
bp.subscribe(Activity, subscriptionID)
```

I get the Google Play purchase window, but the biling period is always 'per day', and the trial period is always '1 day'.

I have configured my subscription to have:

- Billing Period: Yearly
- Free Trial Period: 15 days
- Default Price: $12

Using the above configuration, my App shows the purchase details as:

1 day trial
$12.00 / day

Library documentation says nothing. Tried to Google it, can't find anything.. Am I the only one getting this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a normal response. I guess you're testing with an account added as a tester to Google Play account. Test subscriptions are valid for 1 day and get cancelled after 1 day.

Quoting the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

> Note: Test subscription purchases recur daily, regardless of the
>   product's subscription period.

Comment: Thank you!! And I thought I had gone through the entire docs.. :D

Comment: Double, TRIPLE thank you!!! - I've been fighting and configuring and changing and banging my head on the keyboard for a week, I even gave up for a while and worked on something else.  They really need to put that in bold (goes and checks) well, they kinda did, perhaps I should have RTFM.  Thank you again!