# Why in Google In App Annual Subscription with trial period says Cost/day if its Annual?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I noticed that if I set up a annual subscription with a X cost I get the message of cost/day. Is is true that it has to do with a beta tester account who made the purchase as said here ?

[Android In App BIlling v3 - Wrong Subscription Trial Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444481/android-in-app-billing-v3-wrong-subscription-trial-period)

Additionally why I am not seeing in Merchant Center any Trial Annual Subscriptions

Comment: What Google Support says about it?

Comment: They dont have a live support for that and we just wait the pacific time to answer our email